# Correct synonym for "part"

Tags: synonyms

I'm developing a 3D printing software, where people can color different layers before printing, so it gets printed in colors they want. But I don't know how to name these "parts" in the user interface.

For a better understanding imagine a lighthouse:
[image: Text]

How is a single white (or red) "part" called correct?

I found different synonyms online (slice, fragment, section, piece,  segment, etc), but I'm not sure which to use.

Comment: In ***literal*** terms there's no such thing as "the white part" - that's effectively an "artefact" that arises when we look at the ***picture*** (which happens to include several *different* white things). But in the context of pictures and "image processing" software such as Photoshop, you might well have a white ***layer*** in your source data file.

Comment: I'd call it a **stripe** (or just a [white/red] **bit**).

Comment: If you are interested enough in the topic to create relevant software, then I imagine you are reading way more about it than average people. You should be in a position to see how other insider-to-3D-printing people may call this feature.

Comment: In the meanwhile I like *section* and *segment* from your collection; maybe I would suggest *range* too...